# How to filter a column where you need to separate the data into 4 groups and calculate the percentage of each group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column (x) with values ​​from 0 to 100. I need to separate in 4 groups with the conditions:

- Group 1: x <= 17
- Group 2: x > 17 and x <=50
- Group 3: x>50 and x <=83
- Group 4: x>83

And calculate the percentage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

First i'm creating bins and as cut-off points and assign the names to those bins:

```
bins = [0, 17, 50, 83, np.inf]
names = ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3', 'Group 4]
```

We can create a column, let's say 'Groups' and create your specific categories inside this newly created column.

```
df['Groups'] = pd.cut(df['x'], bins, labels=names
```

percentages can be calculated by getting the length of the group divided by the total length. For example:

```
len(df[df['Groups'] == 'Group 1']) / len(df)
```

Would give you a decimal number. You could do *100 to get the exact percentage.

Comment: And how to calculate the percentage?

Comment: Now I have to create a football field, separate the actions of a given player using different colors for each of the zones created. The command to create the field and the total actions is this: ``` ax = pintar_campo('grey')

df_atleti_position.plot(kind='scatter', x='x', y='y', color='red', ax=ax)

ax.set_title("Mapa de calor de los jugadores de Atletico de Madrid") ```